# All ranges of Unicode letters?

Tags: unicode

Each Unicode code point is assigned to a [character category](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category). I'm looking for a list of ranges which has the category "Letter". Best would be a CSV in the format "FROM_CODEPOINT;TO_CODEPOINT" with all ranges that define letters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Unicode consortium publishes a [database](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/). The `UnicodeData.txt` file contains the character category. I can obtain the ranges from there with a simple utility.